# How to add a new line while creating xml file using VBScripting?

Tags: vbscript

Below is a function which I use in my automation using VBScripting while getting the results in xml file. The result is displayed in a single line now.Please let me know how to add a new line after every "Results" node.I am not able to use "Replace(string, vbCrLf, "")" also. It gives error"Cannot use parentheses while calling a function".

```
Function WriteTestSet(TestSetPath, sheetname, varr )
set wb = xl.workbooks.open(TestSetPath)
set ws = wb.worksheets(sheetname)

rc = ubound(varr, 1) + 1
cc = ubound(varr, 2) + 1

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")  
Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("TestResults")  
xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot

for m= 0 to rc-1
    for n= 0 to 0
        Set objTest = xmlDoc.createElement("TestCaseName")  
        objTest.Text = varr(m,n)
        objRoot.appendChild objTest 

        Set objRun = xmlDoc.createElement("Run")  
        objRun.Text = varr(m,n+1) 
        objRoot.appendChild objRun 

        Set objResult = xmlDoc.createElement("Results")  
        objResult.Text = varr(m,n+2) 
        objRoot.appendChild objResult
    next
next
Set objIntro = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction ("xml","version='1.0'")  
xmlDoc.insertBefore objIntro,xmlDoc.childNodes(3)
ts = replace(replace(now, "/", "_"), ":", "_")
xmlDoc.Save "E:\TestResults\TestSet"& ts & ".xml" 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [XSL style sheet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2012/07/06/creating-quot-pretty-quot-xml-using-xsl-and-vbscript.aspx) too transform the XML into properly spaced indented format.